# Javascript code dosn't work after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I reload a page using ajax but I have a problem that the javascript code work only at the first time then after refreshing it not working,I use this javascript code for ajax :

```
function showUser(str, pageno, type, sub) {
    if (str == "" || pageno == "" || type == "" || sub == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo $view['router']->generate('listing') ?>?page=" + pageno + "&genre=" + str + "&cat=" + type + "&subcat=" + sub, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and in the listing page I do like that :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('test'); //I see alert message only at the first time I run the page
    $("#category-table").tablesorter();
});
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: r u under updatepanel ?

Comment: why don't you use jQuery ajax?

Comment: @VitorVenturin that's not a problem. this also works

Comment: How can you expect `$("#category-table").tablesorter()` to execute after an ajax request automagically? (Hint: it won't.)

Comment: You realize that the whole point of jQuery is to make JavaScript code easier to use and cross-browser compatible right? so you don't have to long hand your AJAX requests and such.

Comment: @VitorVenturin the truth I'm backend developer so I'm not professional in javascript,do you have a code solution for this?

Comment: add `$("#category-table").tablesorter();` to the end of `onreadystatechange `

Comment: Simple. re-execute `$("#category-table").tablesorter();` when you recreate that element.

Comment: @RoyiNamir what you mean?

Comment: @KevinB it's in the place when I recreate the element!

Comment: no it isn't.... it would have to be after this line: `document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jquery's ajax, not only will it fix any cross browser issues for you that might crop up, you also get handy callbacks.

Your issue is that a ready event is not triggered on document, after an ajax request. So you need to use a callback for the ajax request, so once its completed, you can re-run the tablesorter plugin.

You can do this by re-calling that plugin contrustor after you assign the response text to the DIV html. However since you have jquery, you can make things a lot easier for yourself

Change your func to this:

```
function showUser(str, pageno, type, sub) {

    var ele = $('#txtHint');

    if (str == "" || pageno == "" || type == "" || sub == "") {
        ele.html('');
        return;
    }

    ele.load("<?php echo $view['router']->generate('listing') ?>?page=" + pageno + "&genre=" + str + "&cat=" + type + "&subcat=" + sub, function(){

        $("#category-table").tablesorter();

    });


}
```

Comment: *"you also get handy callbacks"* he has handy callbacks with his current solution too, fyi.

Comment: @KevinB: Bad wording admittedly. "more convenient" callbacks (in my opinion) may be a better term.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function showUser(str, pageno, type, sub) {
  var $txtHint = $("#txtHint");
  $txtHint.empty();
  if (str &&  pageno  && type && sub) { // assuming none of them are 0
    $txtHint.load("<?php echo $view['router']->generate('listing') ?>",
    {"page":pageno, "genre":str,"cat":type, "subcat":sub},
      function() {
        $("#category-table").tablesorter();
      }
    );
  }
}
```